# Adding a View to Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to convert the django tutorial app into my own, and with that I need to add a few different views. I've added a new Column called 'Owner' into my database, migrated it, and am now trying to create a new view that will display the Owner data (similar to how the tutorial displays the questions and their data). Any idea what steps I am missing to get past this error?

Expected Output would be for this to open with a functioning page displaying based on the stakeholdes.html file:

```
http://127.0.0.1:7000/polls/stakeholders
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include
from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<int:pk>/stakeholders/', views.StakeholdersView, name='stakeholders'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/results/', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
    path('django_plotly_dash/', include('django_plotly_dash.urls')),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import loader
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views import generic
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Question
from .forms import QuestionForm

def stakeholders(request):
    owner_list = Owner.objects.order_by('-question_id')[:5]
    template = loader.get_template('polls/stakeholders.html')
    context = {
        'owner_list': owner_list,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))

class StakeholdersView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/stakeholders.html'
    context_object_name = 'owner_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return the last five published questions."""
        return Owner.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Question

class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = "__all__"
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
import datetime


class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
    def was_published_recently(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.pub_date <= now
    was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'pub_date'
    was_published_recently.boolean = True
    was_published_recently.short_description = 'Published recently?'


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)# Create your models here.
    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text

class Owner(models.Model):
    owner_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.owner_text
```

[image]

Comment: You have no path matching polls/stakeholders.... the closest you have expect an integer as follow polls/<int:pk>/stakeholders

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your url path!

Now your urls.py are like this:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include
from . import views

    app_name = 'polls'
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
        path('<int:pk>/stakeholders/', views.StakeholdersView, name='stakeholders'),
        path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
        path('<int:pk>/results/', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
        path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
        path('django_plotly_dash/', include('django_plotly_dash.urls')),
    ]
```

It should have some path that includes "polls/stakeholders/", I have include it in your second path:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include
from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('polls/stakeholders/', views.StakeholdersView, name = 'stakeholders'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/results/', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
    path('django_plotly_dash/', include('django_plotly_dash.urls')),
]
```